# Android 4.0 cart badge NullPointerException

Tags: android, menuitem, badge

I'm trying to add a badge to the cart icon on my actionbar like this picture [image]

but I'm facing with the problem that for android 4.0, the app crashed. The first time I launch the app, it works perfect, the badge is setted and then, I click on the icon. Then, the app shows me the cart fragment, and when I click on the back button, is when the app gives me the null pointer exception.
I was following this tutorial http://mobikul.com/adding-badge-count-on-menu-items-like-cart-notification-etc/

I have discovered that the problem came from this line of code:

```
LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
```

Because when I get the icon, it's null. I'm trying with this code before getting the icon:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       itemCart.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_cart_icon));
    }
```

but this doesn't work.

Here is my ic_menu_car.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart_empty"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- set a place holder Drawable so android:drawable isn't null -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_badge"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cart_empty" />
</layer-list>
```

And here is my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cart_option"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_cart_icon"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

And the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(R.id.cart_option);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        itemCart.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_cart_icon));
    }

    LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();

    BadgeDrawable badge;

    // Reuse drawable if possible
    Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
    if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
        badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
    } else {
        badge = new BadgeDrawable(context, R.color.js_pink);
    }

    badge.setCount(count);
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);

}
```

Does anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

After setting LayerDrawble.setDrawableByLayerID()

call menu.setIcon();

refer the below sample code:

private void setBadgeCount(MainNavigationActivity mainNavigationActivity, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {

```
    // Reuse drawable if possible
    Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
    if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
        badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
    } else {
        badge = new BadgeDrawable(mainNavigationActivity);
    }

    badge.setCount(count);
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
    itemCart.setIcon(icon);
}
```